# Feature importance of each variable in GBT Classifier Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How do I get the corresponding feature importance of every variable in a GBT Classifier model in pyspark

Answer (score 3):

From spark 2.0+ ([here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=featureimportance#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.featureImportances)) You have the attribute:

```
model.featureImportances
```

This will give a sparse vector of feature importance for each column/ attribute